# checkdnsrr error with php 2.9.2

Tags: php

i am trying to use checkdnsrr() function with php 2.9.2, but it shows an error as "Call to undefined function checkdnsrr()".. is it because this function is not compatible with the version i am using? Can i have an alias of this function so that it works with my version?

Comment: If you keep tagging with a useless word like "doubt", people will keep ignoring you.

Comment: was there ever a php release 2.9.2, if so why are you using it?

Comment: php 2.9.2? sometime last millennium? maybe you should consider an upgrade after all ...

Comment: can you suggest me some function which has the same operation as checkdnsrr() in php 2.9 version.. is there any such function ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following indicates that the checkdnserr function is only compatible with PHP 4 or 5.

This is taken straight from the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdnsrr.php)

> checkdnsrr
>
> (PHP 4, PHP 5)
>
> checkdnsrr — Check DNS records
>   corresponding to a given Internet host
>   name or IP address

Comment: The manual only indicates which PHP versions are supported; they are not indicative of whether the functions were added in PHP 4.

Answer (score 0):

checkdnsrr work in version 4 and 5. How to even find an manual for Php version 2.9.2 I am not sure!

Answer (score 0):

The function existed in PHP 3, but I cannot confirm whether it existed in PHP 2 or not. Anyhow, PHP 2 and 3 are no longer supported versions. You should upgrade to PHP 4 or later.